# What is the benefit of comapion objects instead of static method and fields?

Tags: java, kotlin, static, companion-object

I ask myself why does Kotlin use companion objects instead of static methods and fields? Is it the reduce of boilerplate? I think it is easier to write companion object with all properties and functions inside curly braces instead of writing static every time. Here is an example.

```
class Hero {
    companion object {
        private var numberOfHeroes = 0

        fun addNewHero() {
            numberOfHeroes++
        }

        fun deleteHero() {
            numberOfHeroes--
        }

        fun getAllHeroes(): Int {
            return numberOfHeroes
        }
    }

    init {
        addNewHero()
    }
}

fun main() {

    val h1 = Hero()
    val h2 = Hero()

    print("Number of heros: ${Hero.getAllHeroes()}") // result is 2
}
```

But is this the only benefit? I know concisness is very important for Kotlin but I think there will be a little bit more.

Comment: It helps to indicate a logical separation between members of the class Vs members of the companion. Static members of a class aren't really part of the class in the object-oriented sense, they are just something which lives in the same namespace. By forcing them to be declared separately, the distinction is maintained, rather than just mixing it all together.

Comment: `companion object` can receive extension functions, and also implement interfaces.

Comment: Okay so you mean that its not really obvious in java that static fields and methods are not really part of the objects? But is that the case with kotlin? I think you have to write it in the class declaration. So the only seperation exists through the companion object wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit (or drawback, for that matter) for doing one or the other. It is just a language construct. And, frankly, you should ask what is the benefit of companion objects *and* extension functions vs static methods.

Java and most other OO languages chose to use static fields for the cases when there must only one instance of the field exist, and static methods for the cases when a) the instance of the class does not matter or is not important, or b) it actually kinda-does, but the developer writing a static method is not in control over the class, i.e. user wants to extend a functionality of the existing class, of which he/she is not the original author (provide a utility-function so to speak).

The example of the latter would be a utility method for the `String` class that checks whether the string in question is blank (consists of only spaces or empty). The `String` class cannot be altered directly by the end users, so a need to write a utility class with static method(s) arises. This task is perfectly addressed in Kotlin using extension functions and/or properties.

Comment: Thank you too for your help. But I think it is an advantage to wrap the "static" methods in a companion object because of the possibility to call extension functions on it. But yes, its a benefit of both together, companion objects and extension functions.

But implementing interfaces is a benefit too in my opinion. So its not completely different to static fields in java but a little difference are available.